# How to get full date from the given month and year in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have following script where I need to get the full date

```
DECLARE @BeginDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime
Declare @month int
Declare @year int 
set @month = 6
set @year = 2014

Select beginDate = CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/01/' + CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(10))
SELECT endDate = DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @beginDate) + 1, 0))
```

This script returns endDate as null. How do I get full endDate by passing only Date (not time)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to put @ sign in front of the variables. If you change the last two lines with the following:

```
Select @beginDate = CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/01/' + CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(10))
SELECT @endDate = DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @beginDate) + 1, 0))
```

it should work. By putting "select @enddate" at the end, I got 2014-06-30 00:00:00.000 .

Answer (score 0):

Well I found it.

```
DECLARE @BeginDate DateTime
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime
Declare @month int
Declare @year int 
set @month = 7
set @year = 2014

Select @beginDate = CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/01/' + CAST(@year AS VARCHAR(10))
SELECT endDate = DATEADD(d, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, @beginDate)), DATEADD(m, 1, @BeginDate))
```

[source](http://sqlmate.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/get-first-and-last-day-of-month-in-sql-2012-and-sql-2008-and-earlier/)